# How can I find out the SeekBar's onStartTrackingTouch provided by default in PlayerNotificationManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, exoplayer, android-seekbar

I'm currently creating a function to track the playback and end times of a video. The Custom SeekBar of a app can get the Player's currentPosition by overriding onStartTrackingTouch before moving. But I'm spending a lot of time with PlayerNotification's SeekBar because I can't find its function.

To solve the problem, I tried to control the SeekBar by creating a view of the notification myself, but RemoteViews does not recommend SeekBar and instead recommends using PlayerNotification's default SeekBar. If you know the solution, please let me know. thank you